# Overriding Directives in Angular Material - Compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I've customized some angular-material components, but I've had to do this in the source code.  I would like to separate the changes from the original angular-material file, but have the new components overwrite the existing components.  I've read about `priority: 1` and `terminal: true` for extending directives, but when I've tried to do this, I am getting an error where I cannot find the controller on an element.  I am simply copy/pasting code I've edited in angular material into my directives file and overwriting all directives with `priority: 1` and `terminal: true` but get an undefined controller in the `.configureAutocomplete` method.

Here is the compile function:

```
function compile(element, attr) {
        // Grab the user template from attr and reset the attribute to null.
        var userTemplate = attr['$mdUserTemplate'];
        attr['$mdUserTemplate'] = null;

        // Set the chip remove, chip contents and chip input templates. The link function will put
        // them on the scope for transclusion later.
        var chipRemoveTemplate   = getTemplateByQuery('md-chips>*[md-chip-remove]') || CHIP_REMOVE_TEMPLATE,
            chipContentsTemplate = getTemplateByQuery('md-chips>md-chip-template') || CHIP_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE,
            chipInputTemplate    = getTemplateByQuery('md-chips>md-autocomplete')
                || getTemplateByQuery('md-chips>input')
                || CHIP_INPUT_TEMPLATE,
            staticChips = userTemplate.find('md-chip');

        // Warn of malformed template. See #2545
        if (userTemplate[0].querySelector('md-chip-template>*[md-chip-remove]')) {
            $log.warn('invalid placement of md-chip-remove within md-chip-template.');
        }

        function getTemplateByQuery (query) {
            if (!attr.ngModel) return;
            var element = userTemplate[0].querySelector(query);
            return element && element.outerHTML;
        }

        /**
         * Configures controller and transcludes.
         */
        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

            $mdUtil.initOptionalProperties(scope, attr);

            $mdTheming(element);
            var mdChipsCtrl = controllers[0];
            mdChipsCtrl.chipContentsTemplate = chipContentsTemplate;
            mdChipsCtrl.chipRemoveTemplate   = chipRemoveTemplate;
            mdChipsCtrl.chipInputTemplate    = chipInputTemplate;

            element
                .attr({ ariaHidden: true, tabindex: -1 })
                .on('focus', function () { mdChipsCtrl.onFocus(); });

            if (attr.ngModel) {
                mdChipsCtrl.configureNgModel(element.controller('ngModel'));

                // If an `md-on-append` attribute was set, tell the controller to use the expression
                // when appending chips.
                if (attrs.mdOnAppend) mdChipsCtrl.useMdOnAppendExpression();

                // The md-autocomplete and input elements won't be compiled until after this directive
                // is complete (due to their nested nature). Wait a tick before looking for them to
                // configure the controller.
                if (chipInputTemplate != CHIP_INPUT_TEMPLATE) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            if (chipInputTemplate.indexOf('<md-autocomplete') === 0) {
                                // *** WHERE PROBLEM IS ***
                                console.log("element: ", element.find('md-autocomplete')); // found element
                                console.log("controller: ", element.find('md-autocomplete').controller('mdAutocomplete')); //undefined
                                mdChipsCtrl
                                    .configureAutocomplete(element.find('md-autocomplete')
                                        .controller('mdAutocomplete'));
                            }
                            mdChipsCtrl.configureUserInput(element.find('input'));
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            // Compile with the parent's scope and prepend any static chips to the wrapper.
            if (staticChips.length > 0) {
                var compiledStaticChips = $compile(staticChips)(scope.$parent);
                $timeout(function() { element.find('md-chips-wrap').prepend(compiledStaticChips); });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't find the controller, but the original (in angular-material.js), which is identical minus the terminal and priority properties finds the controller?  Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Similar issue here. Were you able to solve this?